# Why my LinkedList is filled with the same object?

Tags: java, linked-list

I've been trying to fill in a `LinkedList`. I've written the following code:

```
List<Item> lst = new LinkedList<Item>();
Item item = new Item();
for(ListItem it : getAllItems()){
    item.setDate(it.getDate);
    //Setting up it's property to item
    lst.add(item);
}
```

But after the code above is executed we have `lst` contains a `List` of the same element, which has been added at the last executing of foreach body. I'm expected that we have a `List` of elements which has been set up at any executing of the `foreach` body.

Comment: The `add` of the list adds by reference and you just create one Item at the very beginning. So your are adding the same instance over and over again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are adding the *same* `Item` object in every loop iteration. Since you also change its date each time, it ends up with the very last date set.

```
for(ListItem it : getAllItems()){
   Item item = new Item();
   item.setDate(it.getDate);
   //Setting up it's property to item
   lst.add(item);
}
```

Note that calling `add` does not add a copy of the `item` to the list (which you may have been assuming), but rather adds another *reference* to this `item` to the list.

Answer (score 4):

You need to create a new `Item` object each time *inside* the loop:

```
for(ListItem it : getAllItems()){
    //create a *new* object on each iteration
    Item item = new Item(); 
    item.setDate(it.getDate);
    lst.add(item);
}
```

In your code, you have *one* `Item` object that you always `setDate` on it.

Answer (score 0):

I'll just to improve previous answer provided the sources of LinkedList. Elements of the LinkedList represents by the inner class

```
private static class Node<E> {
        E item;
        Node<E> next;
        Node<E> prev;

        Node(Node<E> prev, E element, Node<E> next) {
            this.item = element;
            this.next = next;
            this.prev = prev;
        }
    }
```

and the `add(E e)` has the following implementation:

```
public boolean add(E e) {
    linkLast(e);
    return true;
}
```

and the `linkLast(E e)` method:

```
void linkLast(E e) {
    final Node<E> l = last;
    final Node<E> newNode = new Node<>(l, e, null);
    last = newNode;
    if (l == null)
        first = newNode;
    else
        l.next = newNode;
    size++;
    modCount++;
}
```

That is, every time we add to the list the `item` we just set up the `last.next = item`, and therefore we have a List of the same `item`.